# Sum of two subspaces is equal to the span of their union

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ be two subspaces of $V$. Define the sum of $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ to be the subset of $V$

$V_{1}+V_{2}=${$ \overrightarrow v_{1} + \overrightarrow v_{2}: \overrightarrow v_{1} \in V_{1}, \overrightarrow v_{2} \in V_{2}$}

Prove that $V_{1}+V_{2}=Span(V_{1} \cup V_{2})$

Approach: I want to prove $V_{1}+V_{2} \subset Span(V_{1} \cup V_{2})$ and $Span(V_{1} \cup V_{2}) \subset V_{1}+V_{2}$. Any tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $x\in V_1+V_2$ then $x=v_1+v_2$ for $v_i\in V_i$. However this immediately implies $x\in Span(V_1\cup V_2)$ because $x$ is a sum of elements from $V_1\cup V_2$. This gives the first inclusion.

If $x\in Span(V_1\cup V_2)$, then I can write $x$ as a sum of elements from $V_1\cup V_2$, say $u_1+w_1+u_2+w_2+\dots+u_k+w_k$, where $u_i\in V_1$ and $w_i\in V_2$. Then I can group these so

$$x=(u_1+\dots+u_k)+(w_1+\dots+w_k)\in V_1+V_2$$

because $u_1+\dots+u_k\in V_1$, and $w_1+\dots+w_k\in V_2$. This gives the other inclusion and you are done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When we say $x \in V_{1}+V_{2}$, does x represent an arbitrary vector? Also shouldn't I give different sub letters for the vectors $\overrightarrow u$ and $\overrightarrow w$?

Comment: Yes, $x$ represents an arbitrary vector of $V_1+V_2$ so it must have the form $v_1+v_2$ by the way you defined $V_1+V_2$. Also, if you mean the letter $k$ then we can use the same number there because we can assume that if say there are more nonzero vectors from $V_1$ than $V_2$ in the sum then $w_m=w_{m+1}=\dots=w_k$ for some $m$.

Comment: I see! Thank you for your input.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the span is the set of (finite) linear combinaisons, not just of finite sums. The argument remains the same though, you just have to add coefficients in front of the $u_i$s and $w_i$s. And having as many elements in $V_1$ and $V_2$ feels a bit weird, even though it doesn't really matter since we can take $k$ large enough and just add zeros.

Comment: @xavierm02 good point, my mistake.

Comment: @Sadem I screwed up my comment and can't edit it now but that was supposed to say $w_m=\dots=w_k=0$.

Comment: what is your reasoning in writing 1+1+2+2 into (1+1), (2+2) pairs instead of 1+u2+1+2? I am curious to what intuition you are using behind that pairing thanks

Comment: since the union is contained in the sum and the sum is a vector space (i.e. stable under linear combinations), the span of the union cannot exceed the sum.

the other direction is just the observation that a sum of vectors is a linear combination.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're on the right track:

To demonstrate this $V_{1}+V_{2} \subset Span(V_{1} \cup V_{2})$ you need to pick a vector $w$ in $V_{1}+V_{2}$ and prove that is in the $Span(V_{1} \cup V_{2})$ writing it as a linear combination of vector of $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ (indeed is trivially from the definition).

The converse $Span(V_{1} \cup V_{2}) \subset V_{1}+V_{2}$ is similar, i.e. pick a vector in the span write it in a base of $Span(V_{1} \cup V_{2})$ then rearrange the term to show that is in $V_{1}+V_{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! First one does seem obvious from the definition. I think the second one is harder only due to notation in regards to spans.

Comment: If the two vector spaces have finite dimension and then have basis you just have to consider that the span of $V_1$ union $V_2$ is the union of the elements of the basis

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\in V_1+V_2$. By definition of $V_1+V_2$, you have $x_1\in V_1$ and $x_2\in V_2$ so that $x = x_1 + x_2$. So...

> $x=x_1+x_2=1\cdot x_1+1\cdot x_2\in \operatorname{Span}(V_1\cup V_2)$ since $x_1\in V_1 \subseteq V_1\cup V_2$ and $x_2\in V_2 \subseteq V_1\cup V_2$.

So we have $x\in \operatorname{Span}(V_1\cup V_2)$.

---

Let $x\in \operatorname{Span}(V_1\cup V_2)$. By definition, there is a finite number (so $1\le i \le n$) of $x_i\in V_1\cup V_2$ and of $\lambda_i\in \mathbb R$ so that $x=\lambda_1\cdot x_1+\dots+\lambda_nx_n$. But each $x_i$ is either in $V_1$ or $V_2$. Let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_p$ be the indices so that $x_{\alpha_i}\in V_1$ and $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_q$ the remaining indices.  We have $x=(\lambda_{\alpha_1}\cdot x_{\alpha_1}+\dots+\lambda_{\alpha_p}\cdot x_{\alpha_p})+(\lambda_{\beta_1}\cdot x_{\beta_1}+\dots+\lambda_{\beta_q}\cdot x_{\beta_q})$. And so...

> We know that $x_{\beta_i}$ will be in $V_1\cup V_2$ and not in $V_1$ so in $V_2$.

-

> Since $V_1$ is a subspace and all the $x_{\alpha_i}$s are in $V_1$, $(\lambda_{\alpha_1}\cdot x_{\alpha_1}+\dots+\lambda_{\alpha_p}\cdot x_{\alpha_p})\in V_1$. For the same reasons, $(\lambda_{\beta_1}\cdot x_{\beta_1}+\dots+\lambda_{\beta_q}\cdot x_{\beta_q})\in V_2$.

And so $x\in V_1+V_2$.

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of question that is hard because of how trivial it is. Just rewrite the RHS and the LHS in terms of their definitions and you basically have a proof.

Comment: I thought $V_{1}+V_{2}$ was already written in terms of its definition. I'm not really sure how to define $Span(V_{1} \cup V_{2})$ algebraically. To me it's the linear combinations of elements pertaining to $V_{1}$ or $V_{2}$

Comment: Well, I mean technically, you could say that any proof is just rewriting stuff in terms of their definitions. The point is do not get scared by notation, notation should be your friend, not your ennemy. For example formulate the problem in words and it is quite a self evident statement. The top answer is basically a rewrite.Think about what those symbols mean. i.e. what is the plus operator when applied to two vector spaces. Actually the statement you are asked to prove could be a good definition for it...

Answer (score 1):

Since the union is contained in the sum and the sum is a vector space (i.e. stable under linear combinations), the span of the union cannot exceed the sum.

The other direction is just the observation that a sum of vectors is a linear combination.